# Running batch file from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file (Windows command line) that creates a VBS file, runs it, and that in turn re-launches the cmd.exe program in elevated mode so that I can copy a file to the System32 folder.

If I run this batch file manually, all goes according to plan, but if I run it from a VBA Excel macro the batch file gets stuck in an infinite loop, even after the UAC prompt has appeared and I have allowed elevated access. Am I calling the batch file incorrectly from VBA?

I'm fine with VBA, OKish with windows CMD, but haven't often used the two together.

I've tried the following statements in my macro, all 3 have the same result:

```
Shell Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\TEMP.bat"

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "CMD /C %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TEMP.bat", 0, False

Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TEMP.bat").StdOut.ReadAll
```

For what it's worth, this is the Batch file code:

---

```cmd
@ECHO OFF
:----------------------
>NUL 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%' NEQ '0' (
GOTO UACPrompt
) ELSE ( GOTO gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%TEMP%\getadmin.vbs"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%TEMP%\getadmin.vbs"

"%TEMP%\getadmin.vbs"

EXIT /B
:gotAdmin

IF EXIST "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( DEL "%TEMP%\getadmin.vbs" )
PUSHD "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:----------------------

:: < REST OF SCRIPT HERE - NOT RELEVANT TO QUESTION >
```

---

And this is what's in the VBS file:

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
UAC.ShellExecute "C:\Users\SO\Desktop\TEMP.bat", "", "", "runas", 1
```

Any pointers/suggestions welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering perhaps is this a permission issue with Excel/CMD.exe...

Comment: Why is this whole process necessary? Why do you dynamically need to create a VBScript file? Why not just convert this VBScript code to Excel VBA and run it directly?

Comment: I could run the VBS code directly from Excel I guess, but I don't think it will solve the issue (I will try just in case and report back) - however - I'm using this code to download/register the mscomct2.ocx file on a Win7 machine if it doesn't exist (DatePicker control doesn't work on Win7 unless this file is installed) I can prompt the user to run the script manually instead, but I'd still like to know what the issue it with calling in from VBA

Comment: A bit of an off topic tip - the `if` command has in built handling of error levels. So you can format your command like so: `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ...`

Comment: @unclemeat I actually copied the script from https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/home/BatchGotAdmin - Point noted though for future reference so cheers.

Comment: You don't need to run the VBS from Excel. You can convert the VBS to Excel VBA (it's not hard) and just run the VBA from Excel. The simpler your system the less likely it is to break. I would be concerned about hard coding administrator logins into your code though.

Comment: So the root cause is you want to "download/register the mscomct2.ocx file on a Win7 machine if it doesn't exist", and you need to do this as an administrator?

Comment: I know I can write the VBS in VBA, the batch code is actually copied from elsewhere I didn't write that bit in but in the process of taking it out anyway. I don't have any logins hardcoded though...?

Comment: ^^ correctomondo, but preferably without user interaction, other than to press OK on the UAC prompt. Like I said, all works fine unless the batch file is called from VBA

Comment: Consider using **RunAs**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks for the suggestion, currently trying that out - however it seems no matter which way I tackle this, the batch file doesn't have access to any system directories when called from Excel, even with the ShellExecute/RunAs method. If I run the batch file manually it's fine. I may take a different approach to this problem altogether...

Comment: @SO Good luck! Please update this post if you discover a solution.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thank you, and of course I will update this post with any findings!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem, and below code solved it. Howerver, the problem is Shell doesn't have bWaitOnReturn option.

```
Dim Foldername As String
Foldername = "C:\WorkspaceRFT\RMS\command.bat"
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```